# how to send cookies inside post request

Tags: python, post, cookies, urllib2, urllib

trying to send Post request with the cookies on my pc from get request

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import re #regex
import urllib
import urllib2
#get request 
x = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com) #GET Request
cookies=x.headers['set-cookie'] #to get the cookies from get request 

url = 'http://example' # to know the values type any password to know the cookies 
values = {"username" : "admin",
          "passwd" : password,
          "lang" : "" ,
          "option" : "com_login",
          "task" : "login",
          "return" : "aW5kZXgucGhw" }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
result = response.read() 
cookies=response.headers['set-cookie'] #to get the last cookies from post req in this variable
```

then i searched in google

how to send cookies inside same post request  and found

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener() # send the cookies
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', cookies)) # send the cookies
f = opener.open("http://example")
```

but i don't exactly where should i type it  in my code

what i need to do exactly is to

send GET request, put the cookies from the request in variable,then make post request with the value that i got from the GET request

if anyone know answer i need edit on my code

Answer (score 2):

Just create a HTTP opener and a cookiejar handler. So cookies will be retrieved and will be passed together to next request automatically. See:

```
import urllib2 as net
import cookielib
import urllib   

cookiejar = cookielib.CookieJar()
cookiejar.clear_session_cookies()
opener = net.build_opener(net.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar))

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
request  = net.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(data))
response = opener.open(request)
```

As `opener` is a global handler, just make any request and the previous cookies sent from previous request will be in the next request (POST/GET), automatically.

Comment: can you edit my code please because from trying from long time  i feel like confused

Comment: & i need just 1 POST request not 2 ,, if 2 post request that won't help me :( ,, i need 1 POST request with the parameters & cookies ( that i get from get request)

Comment: @smile As opener is a global handler, just make a next request and the previous cookies sent from previous request will be in  the next request (POST/GET), automatically.

Comment: i don't understand you well :( ,,, YOU will make GET request and 1 post request like what i want ??

Comment: cookiejar = cookielib.CookieJar()
NameError: name 'cookielib' is not defined

Comment: @smile "import cookielib"

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into the requests library python has to offer.  All you need to do is make a dictionary for you cookies key/value pair and pass it is as an arg.

Your entire code could be replaced by

```
#import requests
url = 'http://example' # to know the values type any password to know the cookies
values = {"username" : "admin",
                  "passwd" : password,
                  "lang" : "" ,
                  "option" : "com_login",
                  "task" : "login",
                  "return" : "aW5kZXgucGhw" }
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url, data=values)
cookies = session.cookies.get_dict()
response = reqeusts.post(url, data=values, cookies=cookies)
```

The second piece of code is probably what you want, but depends on the format of the response.

Comment: i need to send the cookies that i have from the get request then send it in post request

Comment: I removed the first section. Don't worry about it.  New code shows how to use cookies in a post. You can change the data for whatever it needs to be or leave it out.

Comment: so i should replace data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
result = response.read() 
 with your code right

Comment: The beauty of the requests library is you don't need to use that urllib2 stuff. The code as I wrote it will work.

Comment: Be sure to #import requests

Comment: You're going to have to install then. Google how, takes 2 minutes.

Comment: NameError: name 'reqeusts' is not defined